# How to pin multiple files at once in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I did a lot of research and failed with pinning multiple files at once in VSS. Is there  a way at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official answer for this:

[How To Pin Multiple Files in Visual SourceSafe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193577)

Comment: I usually add a comment thanking people who answered and letting them know if it worked. I didnot find anything on the interface which allows me to accept as answer.

Comment: Thanks Yelton for the reply. I looked at this link previously. According to the link, it is possible to pin multiple files only with same version. There is definitely not always a good chance to pin same version of all files under the project.